# RAID array creation in macOS

Tags: macos, disk-utility, raid

I have a LaCie 2big Thunderbolt 3 RAID drive. I'm currently using LaCie RAID Manager software to create RAID array.

I noticed that MacOS is recognizing the RAID volume as an external drive instead of a RAID set whereas in LaCie RAID Manager, it is detected as a RAID array. If i try to create RAID set using RAID Assistant via macOS Disk Utility instead, LaCie RAID Manager does not recognize the volume as a RAID array.

Would it be better to use LaCie RAID Manager to create RAID array/set instead of macOS Disk Utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is going on here is both expected behavior and an exercise in learning a little terminology.

It is normal for a Mac to see a *third party created* RAID array as a single disk (which I am assuming it does) In both the Finder and Disk Utility? Why? Because the LaCie utility is designed to create RAID arrays that are completely transparent (or if you prefer *invisible*) to the operating system.

The converse is also correct, if you create a RAID array with Apple Disk Utility the LaCie utility will just see it as a single disk.

I work with Windows/ESX servers at work and RAID is created in the firmware of the RAID controller, before the operating system even loads. So both Windows and ESX see the RAID slices as individual disks even though the RAID array knows that there are 6 physical drives set up in a RAID-5 array.

There may be reasons to use the LaCie software over Apple's Disk Utility (or vice-versa) but I am not aware of the relative merits of each utility.

**BUT** You can be assured that what you are seeing (if I understand correctly) is entirely normal and expected behavior.

Comment: Disk Utility creates software RAIDs. This means macOS is responsible for managing the disks and using computer resources. From the sounds of it, this LaCie disk has a built in RAID controller. That would make it a hardware RAID. Along with being more reliable, it allows the set to be connected to any other computer or OS while acting the same.